# rotation cell stops media player android

Tags: java, android, media-player

My code plays a song from a listview, everything perfect, BUT, if I specifically rotate it, the media player stop, how can i keep it playing?
and! if i create an another button to pause, or something like that, should I use the same answer?
my code in a button:

```
testme.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(nombre.matches("Kaminomi")) { //ignore this
                    try {
                        mp.setDataSource(nombreSong);
                        mp.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (validar == false) {
                        validar = true;
                        mp.start();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reproduciendo ahora: \n" + nombreSong, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        testme.setText("Stop :D");
                        testme.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.nisekoi1,0,0,0);
                    } else {
                        validar = false;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deteniendo: \n" + nombreSong, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mp.stop();

                        testme.setText("Play :D");
                    }
                }else{
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Algo mas creo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //ignore this too
                }
}
```

Comment: Have you read [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29)

Comment: no, i haven't, i will check it out!, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your manifest xml file:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

i.e. add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to the activity xml element.

Whats happening is that when your screen orientation changes, a configuration change occurs and this causes Android to destroy and recreate your activity.

The above code in my answer will prevent a configuration change from happening when an orientation change or a keyboard change occurs.

However this is just a workaround. A configuration change can occur at any time (e.g. placing the phone in a docking station) and therefore just disabling configuration changes for orientation changes and keyboard changes is not enough.

To properly maintain the state of objects during configuration changes, Fragments are a good approach.